# SQL recursive query same table

Tags: sql

I have a situation where I have to extract data from a non well designed database.
I have two tables

```
tableA
+----+----------+-----+---------+
| ID | NAME     | AGE | UNIT_ID |
+----+----------+-----+---------+
| 1  | Brown    |  25 | 50      |
| 2  | White    |  27 | 100     |
| 3  | Gilmour  |  24 | 150     |
+----+----------+-----+---------+

tableB
+-----+----------+--------+--------+
| ID  | DESC     | ID_LV1 | ID_LV2 |
+-----+----------+--------+--------+
| 20  | Unit_20  |  20    | 40     |
| 40  | Unit_40  |  40    | 50     |
| 50  | Unit_50  |  100   | 40     |
| 100 | Unit_100 |  100   | 50     |
| 150 | Unit_150 |  50    | 20     |
+-----+----------+--------+--------+
```

ID_LV1 and ID_LV2 are linked to ID of the same table (tableB)

The goal is to run a query and get these results:

```
+----+----------+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| ID | NAME     | AGE | UNIT_DESC | LV1_DESC  | LV2_DESC  |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1  | Brown    | 25  | Unit_50   | Unit_100  | Unit_40   |
| 2  | White    | 27  | Unit_100  | Unit_100  | Unit_50   |
| 3  | Gilmour  | 24  | Unit_150  | Unit_50   | Unit_20   |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

My SQL is pretty rusty. The SQL server that I'm working with doesn't allow me to create views.
My last chance is to import in excel and run a vlookup :-)!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your desired result simply using `inner join`

```
 create table tableA( ID int, NAME varchar(100), AGE int, UNIT_ID int);
 
 insert into tableA values( 1  , 'Brown'    ,  25 , 50      );
 insert into tableA values( 2  , 'White'    ,  27 , 100     );
 insert into tableA values( 3  , 'Gilmour'  ,  24 , 150     );

 
 create table tableB( ID  INT, DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(100), ID_LV1 INT, ID_LV2 INT);
 INSERT INTO tableB values( 20  , 'Unit_20'  ,  20    , 40     );
 INSERT INTO tableB values( 40  , 'Unit_40'  ,  40    , 50     );
 INSERT INTO tableB values( 50  , 'Unit_50'  ,100   , 40     );
 INSERT INTO tableB values( 100 , 'Unit_100' ,  100   , 50     );
 INSERT INTO tableB values( 150 , 'Unit_150' ,  50    , 20     );
```

Query:

```
 select a.ID, a.Name, a.Age,b.Description, b_lv1.Description, b_lv2.Description from tableA a 
               inner join tableB b on a.UNIT_ID=b.ID
               inner join tableB b_lv1  on b.ID_LV1=b_lv1.ID
               inner join tableB b_lv2  on b.ID_LV2=b_lv2.ID
 order by a.ID
```

Output:

| ID | Name | Age | Description | Description | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Brown | 25 | Unit_50 | Unit_100 | Unit_40 |
| 2 | White | 27 | Unit_100 | Unit_100 | Unit_50 |
| 3 | Gilmour | 24 | Unit_150 | Unit_50 | Unit_20 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=57fd8f9a61777bd1f22988caeebb8af0)*